# Difference between asp and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

What is the difference between asp and asp.net?

Comment: Google serves better than SO for this question, as the first answer stands top in Google search

Answer (score 36, accepted):

"Classic" ASP uses vbscript for its code. ASP.NET allows you to use C#, VB.NET and other languages.
ASP.NET gives you access to all the tools which come with the .NET framework and allows you to write object-oriented code.

Comment: - I'm so sorry - I downvoted this by mistake (instead of upvoting) my apologies as I cannot change my vote now; thank you for the informative answer.

Answer (score 14):

They are too numerous to list here. I suggest you read [ASP.NET compared with classic ASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Web_Forms#ASP.NET_compared_with_Classic_ASP) Wikipedia.

--

Aside: My original answer referred to a resource on w3schools.com that is today no longer available. If you would like to access it, you may do so by utilizing the Wayback archive: [ASP.NET vs ASP](http://web.archive.org/web/20100114001028/http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_vsasp.asp).

Comment: Wikipedia link is not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Web_Forms#ASP.NET_compared_with_Classic_ASP

Answer (score 5):

ASP.NET is not the same as ASP. The "old" ASP is now called classic ASP.
ASP.NET is a [Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) can, among other things, use the server controls to run elements.

As for example:

```
<form id="MyForm" runat="server">
```

Then you said that it will run on the server and you have an id to control it.

- NET is the framework (such as a
  library)
- C #, J #, VB.NET, they are the main
  [script languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) for communicating with.
  NET
- ASP.NET is [Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) . 
  it runs on the server side. It generates xml / html / xHTML even further, to the user. In many ways one can compare ASP.NET, with WinForms. Then there is a way to visually show something to the user.

Answer (score 3):

According to [IndiaBIX's answers to ASP.NET interview questions](https://www.indiabix.com/technical/dotnet/asp-dot-net/):

> The basic difference between ASP and ASP.NET is that ASP.NET is compiled whereas ASP is interpreted whereas. This implies that since ASP mainly uses VBScript, when an ASP page is executed, it is interpreted. On the other hand, ASP.NET uses.NET languages, such as C# and VB.NET, which are compiled to Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL).

Also see [the section of the Wikipedia article that compares ASP.NET to ASP classic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET#ASP.NET_compared_with_Classic_ASP) for a detailed comparison.

Answer (score 2):

ASP is older (also called "classic ASP"). ASP.NET is newer, using the .NET framework.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_vsasp.asp

Answer (score 1):

Classical ASP had no mechanism of running itself on non- Microsoft technology platforms like the 'The Apache Web Server'

But, ASP.NET

ASP.NET could be run on non-Microsoft Platforms also. Cassini is a sample Web server produced by Microsoft which, among other projects, has been used to host ASP.NET with Apache.

Multi Language Support in WebPage

In ASP only two languages were available for scripting VBScript and Jscript/Javascript.
But in ASP.NET
We are no longer constrained to the two scripting languages available in traditional ASP: Any fully compliant .NET language can now be used with ASP.NET, including C# and VB.NET.

Note :- (C# and VB.Net are both server Side languages.)