# Using ASP.net with VBScript

Tags: asp.net, vbscript, asp-classic

The company that previously managed our company's website told my boss that they used ASP.net 4.5.2 with our website and the default script engine was listed as VBScript version 5.8.18098. 
My boss is wanting me to familiarize myself with the code so I can take over managing the website in-house but from everything I've read you can't use VBScript with ASP.net, just ASP. Am I misunderstanding?

My main questions are:

1) Can we use VBScript with ASP.net or are they actually using ASP?

2) Is there enough of a difference with ASP and ASP.net that this would be an issue anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not wrong.

1. ASP.Net is compiled language where as VBScript is Scripting Runtime, the confusion comes from ASP (also known as Classic ASP) that used Scripting Languages to power it's server-side scripting functionality.
2. Yes, the two have similarities in their syntax *(if using VB.Net)* but ASP.Net is vastly more powerful and structured approach to building Enterprise Level Web Applications.

Also see [Difference between asp and asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1997562/692942)

Answer (score 0):

"Classic" ASP uses vbscript for its code. ASP.NET allows you to use C#, VB.NET and other languages. ASP.NET gives you access to all the tools which come with the .NET framework and allows you to write object-oriented code.
[See more @ this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997562/difference-between-asp-and-asp-net)

Comment: Not only VBScript, it supports any Active Scripting runtime.